# Upload a file to REST Endpoint using LogicApp

Tags: rest, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake

I have been trying to send a file to a Rest Endpoint using Azure Logic App.

I have the files(2 simple txt files) in Data Lake storage (also tried with BLOB Storage).
I am accessing the file using for each loop, to get the list of files from DLS, and then sending the file name in my POST request.
headers include-
content-type:multipart/form-data
authorization:token
accept: application/json

Body includes
{"file": "filename;type=text/plain", "structureId": "unqiuecode"}

but I get the error service unavailable (Error 503).

When I try the from the Swagger UI, it works perfectly fine.
The only difference I see in the Curl command generated is at symbol
"file:**@**abc.txt;type=text/plain"

The Endpoint accepts file as "String($binary)". I tried base64toBinary but I get error cannot be invoked with the parameter. I have tried several other options, but no success :(

Anyone faced similar issues before?

Thanks,
Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

You can use `binary()` method to do it, like:

[image]

You can also do it like this:

[image]